# What should I include in Git project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

My webapp is written in Ruby on Rails. I'm new to git and want to know what kind of files should I include in the project. Please mention what files should I push into git projects.

Comment: source files of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to ask what files should not be included.

Take this .gitignore file as template https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm looking for.Thanks for including the template link for .gitignore file.